# String format in imageJ macro

Tags: java, macros, imagej, fiji

I would like to convert an integer into a string with leading zeros in ImageJ / Fiji macro editor using `String.format()` function. With this code:

```
s = String.format("%04d", 13);
print(s);
```

I get the following error:

```
Unrecognized String function in line 2
s = String . <format> ("%04d" , 13);
```

Any ideas?

After the documentation https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/functions.html#S this should work:

> String.format(format, number) - Returns a formatted string using the specified format and number.

Version: ImageJ 1.53c with Java 1.8.0_172 (64-bit)

Comment: I get a different error on `(Fiji Is Just) ImageJ 2.1.0/1.53i; Java 1.8.0_172 [64-bit]`. It looks like a bug to me. You could use `String.pad(n, length)` as an alternative. It will add leading zeros.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately `String.pad()` throws the same error for `pad`.  I ended up using the following workaround: `s = toString(13); while (s.length() < 4) {s = "0" + s;}`

Comment: Glad it's solved. Try updating ImageJ. There's something in the release notes about String.pad in 1.53g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `String.format` macro function [requires ImageJ 1.53d or newer](https://github.com/imagej/ImageJA/blob/v1.53d/release-notes.html#L61-L62). The version of ImageJ 1.x shipped with Fiji is a few versions behind due to breaking changes in ImageJ 1.x that the ImageJ2 team still need to work around. In the meantime, you can use the *Help > Update ImageJ...* command to update the version of ImageJ 1.x bundled with Fiji. Be aware that this command will hard quit your running ImageJ instance after downloading the chosen version.